# Accessing Files Downloaded from Apple-Hosted In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm building an app which has non-consumable in-app purchases hosted on Apple's servers. I've been successful in getting my in-app purchases to download, but when I save them to the documents directory, I can't seem to locate or access them afterwards.

Here is the function I use to download the file from the download's contentURL. It is called after the download is completed, passing in download.contentURL to move it's location in the cache to the documents folder.

```
-(void)downloadFromURL: (NSURL *) temporaryURL {
    NSLog(@"The download's contentURL is %@", temporaryURL.absoluteString);
    NSString *folderName = [[temporaryURL path] lastPathComponent];
    NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *folder = [pathArr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSError *writeError = nil;
    NSData *downloadData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:temporaryURL];
    [downloadData writeToURL: fileURL options:0 error:&writeError];

    if( writeError) {
    NSLog(@"Error in writing file %@' : \n %@ ", filePath , writeError);
    return;
    }
    NSLog(@"File successfully downloaded. Url is %@",fileURL.absoluteString);
    myFileURL = fileURL;
}
```

myFileURL is a global variable that is called upon later to initialize an AVAudioPlayer, but when I call

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[myFileURL path]]){
        NSLog(@"File DOES NOT exist at that url");
    } else{
        NSLog(@"File DOES exist at that url");
    }
```

It says that a file does not exist at that path. Any ideas or simple ways to write and access in app purchase content downloaded from apple's servers? I've also tried adding "/Contents/filename.mp3" to the end of the URL to no avail.

Comment: I used your code `-(void)downloadFromURL: (NSURL *) temporaryURL` and got the log message `File successfully downloaded. Url is file:///var/mobile/Applications/B8ED2BDF-513B-479F-92EA-A23C3C0725C0/Documents/C6011299-89C0-4D61-96BF-572D7EF3793E.zip`.However, When I use iExplorer to look at the Documents folder, I cannot see any copied files. Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 5):

Resolved using the code found here: http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6

Comment: Hi I've the same problem, and I've difficult to understand what i have to do in 'MyConfig' in the link you posted, please can you help me?